# How to add if statements to an object block

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, if-statement, contextmenu

This script works, and is an example script which constructs a context menu.. but I need it to construct it differently based on what is clicked.  How can I apply if statements to each of the items in the list, such as hiding the 'edit' item if a condition is met, etc.

```
    $(function(){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one', 
        build: function($trigger, e) {
            return {
                items: 
                {
                    "edit": 
                    {
                        name: "Edit",
                        icon: "edit",
                        callback: function(key, options) 
                        {
                            // some code to perform
                        }
                    },
                    "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
                    "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
                    "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
                    "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
                    "sep1": "---------",
                    "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
                }   
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

```
var foo = {
  bar: {
    baz: (function() {
      // some code here
      return "value";
    })()
  }
};

foo.bar.baz // => "value"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct items object and then return it:

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one',
    build: function ($trigger, e) {
        var items = {
            "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
            "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
            "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
        };

        if (someCondition) {
            items.edit = {
                name: "Edit",
                icon: "edit",
                callback: function(key, options) {
                    // some code to perform
                }
            };
        }

        return {items: items};
    }
});
```

This way you can define some properties before you return items.